# PHP Unwillingly redirected to another page, not allowing me to log in

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm quite new to PHP and I need help: I have a login page for admin, but once I click on the "login" button it immediately redirects me to the admin page, saying I don't have access to it, obviously, since I wasn't even able to log in as admin.

This is the php on my login page, I added everything in this edit:

```
<?php

session_start();
 
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: admin.php");
    exit;
}
 
require_once "config.php";
 
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Fill in your username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Fill in password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
 
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            $param_username = $username;
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                   
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            header("location: admin.php");
                        } else{
                            $login_err = "Invalid";
                        }
                    }
                } else{

                 ...
               }
            } else{
               ...
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Here is my HTML code (and some PHP) of the form:

```
   <h2>Login Admin</h2>
    <p>Fill in your details.</p>

        <?php 
        if(!empty($login_err)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
        }        
        ?>
 
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Something must have set the session variable to `true`.

Comment: Presumably somehow the Session variable is already set somehow. At a guess, maybe it wasn't cleared properly after an earlier logout. But we don't know, we can't see what else is going on. We also don't know what checks your admin page makes when you go there. We can't help without more context.

Comment: @ADyson i edited the post and included admin.php 's information. could this be it?

Comment: You've shown no code for the login.  Your problem is not in the code you have posted.

Comment: I've added in all of the PHP code, I noticed there's another part that mentions "true" how could I fix this?

Comment: Where is your HTML? The problem may have nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @kmoser I added the html that includes the form. if there's anything else, let me know please

Comment: Looks like these 2 lines need to be reversed. 'mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username); $param_username = $username;'.  Seems you use $param_username before you define it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code is missing a closing } character.  Unless it is a copy/paste error.  Here is your corrected code (includes correction in my comment):

```
<?php
session_start();
 
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true)
{
 header("location: admin.php");
 exit;
}

require_once "config.php";

$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
 if(empty(trim($_POST["username"])))
 {
  $username_err = "Fill in your username.";
 }
 else
 {
  $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
 }
 if(empty(trim($_POST["password"])))
 {
  $password_err = "Fill in password.";
 }
 else
 {
  $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
 }

 if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err))
 {
  $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
  if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))
  {
   $param_username = $username;
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
   if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
   {
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1)
    {                   
     mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
     if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
     {
      if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password))
      {
       session_start();
       $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
       $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
       $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
       header("location: admin.php");
      }
      else
      {
       $login_err = "Invalid";
      }
     }
    }
    else
    {
     ...
    }
   }
   else
   {
    ...
   }
   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  }
 }
 mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

I noticed you switched from using PDO to mysqli.  Too bad, I think PDO is better and less verbose.